# How long is a Google Authenticator export valid and can it be used/imported multiple times?

Tags: google-authenticator

Title says it all. Have to put in extra characters to make it a valid post.

Thanks.

Comment: [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says: "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem", not "Write a title that ask a question".  The question will become _unclear_ when you start typing "Have to put in extra characters to make it a valid post."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QR code exported by Google Authenticator should be valid forever and can be imported as many times as you wish because it uses TOTP technology.

You will notice the phone doesn't need to be connected to internet to generate the QR code this is because it combines the OTP (you entered the OTP when adding the 2FA) and a secret.